# Is it possible to chart multi value, ";" delimited cells in Google Viz API?

Tags: datatable, google-visualization

I have a Google Sheet that's sort of set up like this

```
    [['user', lang'],
    ['user1', 'eng'],
    ['user2', 'eng;fre'],
    ['user3', 'eng;ger'],
    ...]
```

Is it possible to use Google Visuzalisation API to draw charts from this table that count up the the values delimited by ";" in the 'lang' column separately,

so that for ex, a table chart would be displayed as

```
    'lang', 'count'
    'eng', '3'
    'fre', '1'
    'ger', '1'
```

Consequently is it possible to have other charts follow this; like if I get a % pie chart, the result would be

```
    eng 100%
    fre 33%
    ger 33%
```

Or must I create separate datatables where a row is a unique combination of every possibility?
i.e.

```
     [['user', lang'],
     ['user1', 'eng'],
     ['user2', 'eng'],
     ['user2', 'fre'],
     ['user3', 'eng'],
     ['user3', 'ger']
     ...]
```

Is it possible to avoid this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

some manipulation is required.

google has a [group](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#google_visualization_data_group) method we can use to count / summarize by language

but first, we will need to split the list for each user

```
  // split lang on semi-colon
  var list = row[1].split(';');
  list.forEach(function (lang) {
    // add row for each lang
    chartData.push([lang]);
  });
```

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart', 'table']
}).then(function () {
  var arrayData = [
    ['user', 'lang'],
    ['user1', 'eng'],
    ['user2', 'eng;fre'],
    ['user3', 'eng;ger'],
    ['user4', 'fre;ger'],
  ];

  var chartData = [];

  // process each data row
  arrayData.forEach(function (row, index) {
    if (index === 0) {
      // column heading
      chartData.push([row[1]]);
    } else {
      // split lang on semi-colon
      var list = row[1].split(';');
      list.forEach(function (lang) {
        // add row for each lang
        chartData.push([lang]);
      });
    }
  });

  // create google data table
  chartData = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(chartData);

  // group data table by lang
  var groupData = google.visualization.data.group(
    chartData,
    [0],
    [{
      column: 0,
      type: 'number',
      label: 'count',
      aggregation: google.visualization.data.count
    }]
  );

  var pie = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('pie'));
  pie.draw(groupData, {width: 300});
  var table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('table'));
  table.draw(groupData);
});
```

```css
.dashboard {
  text-align: center;
}

.chart {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div class="dashboard">
  <div class="chart" id="pie"></div>
</div>
<div class="dashboard">
  <div class="chart" id="table"></div>
</div>
```